# Grep and print to stdout at the same time in loop condition

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm running a test every 60 seconds until it fails. It works fine but I would like to print the output of "npm test" at the same time.

```
until npm test | grep -m 1 "fail"; do sleep 60 ; done && say fail
```

I've tried using tee as in the next command but it just runs the loop once:

```
until npm test | tee >(grep -m 1 "fail"); do sleep 60 ; done && say fail
```

I'm using OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
until npm test | tee /dev/stderr | grep -m 1 "fail"; do sleep 60 ; done && say fail
```

The output of npm test is tee'd to stderr. So the same text goes to stdout and stderr. Stdout is processed by grep and stderr is printed to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

```
exec 3>&1; 
until npm test | tee >(cat >&3) | grep -q -m 1 "fail"; do sleep 60 ; done && say fail
```

`exec` opens new file descriptor with the number `3` which redirects it's output to file descriptor `1`, which is stdout.

Then in `until` condition we `tee` the output into file descriptor 3.

You can be a smarty and save `cat`s:

```
exec 3>&1; 
until npm test | tee /proc/self/fd/3 | grep -q -m 1 "fail"; do sleep 60 ; done && say fail
```